# Save ip camera video to google drive using apps script UrlFetchApp

Tags: google-apps-script, ip-camera

My idea was to setup a script with GAS to record videos of my ip camera to google drive. Currently it can access the camera videostream, take data and save it do drive. It's not working because instead of getting a limited amount of data due to the http request header range parameter it takes the maximum size the http request could receive. Furthermore the asf video seems to get corrupted, and can't be played on VLC.

Any idea for making the script download a defined video size and in the correct format?

```
function myFunction() {
  var URL = 'http://201.17.122.01:82/videostream.asf?user=xxxx&pwd=xxxxxx&resolution=32&rate=1';     // file to backup
  var chunkSize = 1048576; // read the file in pieces of 1MB
  var chunkStart = 0, chunkEnd = chunkStart + chunkSize;

  var chunkHTTP = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL, {
      method: "get",
    contentType: "video/x-ms-asf",
      headers: {
        "Range": "bytes=" + chunkStart + "-" + chunkEnd
      }
    })
    var chunk = chunkHTTP.getContentText();

      // write to Drive
      try {
        var folder = DocsList.getFolder('bakfolder');
      } catch(err) {
        var folder = DocsList.createFolder('bakfolder');
      }
      fileOnDrive = folder.createFile('ipcamera.asf', chunk);

    Logger.log("  %s bytes written to drive", chunk.length);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have an ip camera, so can't test and help you with the chunking of received data. But I suspect that you are using wrong methods for extracting received video data and saving it to Drive:

a) **.getContentText()** method gets the content of an HTTP response *encoded as a string* - probably wrong for working with video stream data. Try using .getBlob() or .getContent() instead;

b) **folder.createFile(name, content)** method creates a *text file* in the current folder. Use .createFile(blob) method instead.

You will most likely have t experiment with the stream bytes to get it as a blob Apps Script can work with. If I find an ip camera or another video stream I can access, I will test it out and update this.

Comment: I changed getContentText() to getBlob and changed createFile(name, content) to createFIle(blob) and the file saved is no longer corrupted. Thanks a lot

Comment: Now the only open point is how to use UrlFetchApp.fetch to get limited amount of data. Header range parameter seems to be ignored, and UrlFetchApp runs for 60 seconds, which I believe is an apps script time limit.

Comment: Yay! At least half the problems solved! No luck with IP camera for me, yet... Trying to find some public video stream that accepts parameters like yours to test it, but again no luck yet. Meanwhile, double-check the camera's documentation to make sure you are sending correct headers for the byte range. What's the model and make of your camera?

Comment: Furthermore, check that your camera / media server actually supports byte serving (partial content serving): do the response headers include _Accept-Ranges_ header? To check this, add this line `Logger.log(chunkHTTP.getAllHeaders().toSource());` before your `var chunk=...` declaration, run your function then check the logs.

Comment: Tested it with just a video (FLV) file hosted on a web server (so not exactly an ip camera feed, but similar), and it worked just fine: only 1048577 bytes saved to Drive out of 21273961 bytes total file size. Here's the log output:
`[14-09-25 12:10:54:410 SGT] ({Content-Length':"1048577", 'Content-Type':"video/x-flv", 'Accept-Ranges':"bytes", 'Content-Range':"bytes 0-1048576/21273961"})
[14-09-25 12:10:57:575 SGT] 1048577.0
[14-09-25 12:10:59:250 SGT]   1048577.0 bytes written to drive
[14-09-25 12:10:59:250 SGT]   created file size: 1048577.0 bytes`

Comment: On a side note, I suggest you use Drive service [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/) instead of DocsList service to interact with Drive in your script. DocsList is/was an experimental service and will likely be eventually deprecated like Documents List API was when Google Drive API came about.

Comment: HTTP server seems to not accept byte serving. [14-10-01 11:34:57:911 BRT] ({Date:"Wed, 01 Oct 2014 14:34:13 GMT", Connection:"close", 'Content-Type':"video/x-ms-asf", Server:"Netwave IP Camera", Pragma:"features=broadcast"})